# MySQL query to calculate a ratio using a subset of rows from a table

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table SeatTracking that tracks the number of seats used in a given room.
The table has three columns: roomID, type, value.

Here's an example of the data:

| roomID | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | occupied | 20 |
| 1001 | vacant | 10 |
| 1002 | occupied | 5 |
| 1002 | vacant | 95 |

I know how to write a query returning the total number of seats in each room.

```sql
SELECT roomID,SUM(value) AS total_seats FROM SeatTracking GROUP BY roomID;
```

I also know how to write a query returning the total number of vacant seats in each room.

```sql
SELECT roomID,SUM(CASE type WHEN 'vacant' THEN value END) AS vacant_seats FROM SeatTracking GROUP BY roomID;
```

Here's the part I'm struggling with - I want to return a vacancy rate for each room. Can someone please point me in the right direction here? Thank you!

I tried the below but I get an error - `"you have an error in your SQL syntax:`

```sql
SELECT roomID, (SUM(CASE type WHEN 'vacant' THEN value END)/SUM(CASE type WHEN 'occupied' THEN value END))*100 AS vacancy_rate 
FROM SeatTracking GROUP BY roomID;
```

I also tried being more explicit, but I get an error unknown column vacant_seats in field list:

```sql
SELECT roomID, SUM(CASE type WHEN 'vacant' THEN value END) AS vacant_seats, 
SUM(CASE type WHEN 'occupied' THEN value END) AS occupied_seats,
(vacant_seats/occupied_seats)*100 AS vacancy_rate 
FROM SeatTracking GROUP BY roomID;
```

Comment: What does the near part of the syntax error message say?

Comment: `SELECT roomID, (SUM(CASE type WHEN 'vacant' THEN value END)/SUM(CASE type WHEN 'occupied' THEN value END))*100 AS vacancy_rate FROM SeatTracking GROUP BY roomID;` It looks like there are no syntax errors. Also, is the desired query `(SUM(CASE type WHEN 'vacant' THEN value END)/SUM(value))*100 AS vacancy_rate`?

Comment: Your query looks correct, you haven't provided the full error.

Comment: Please provide the table schema and sample data. or use a dbfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    (SUM
        (
            CASE type
            WHEN 'vacant' THEN value
            END
        ) / SUM(
            CASE type
            WHEN 'occupied' THEN value
            END
        ) * 100
    ) AS vacancy_rate
FROM
    SeatTracking;
```

Simplest query that will work. [Query output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjvRP.png)